# What are some items still existing today that were involved in the most killings?

Tags: weapons

I was reading recently about how there are sacrificial altars in Mayan culture which over the course of their lifetime of usage probably had several thousands of people sacrificed on them individually. That got me thinking, what are some items that are still in existence today that have been involved in the most killings? In order to avoid making the question too broad I will say that involvement requires that the item must have at least made physical contact with the person who was to be killed, so something like a knife or a guillotine would count, but the plane that dropped a nuclear bomb would not.

Comment: If you're not counting a plane dropping a bomb, then presumably you're not including field artillery or machine guns or rifles too. Hand melee weapons are probably the most likely items to be included but the numbers killed are potentially much lower. You also introduce the "Grandfather's axe" problem, i.e. at what point does the weapon stop being the same weapon when you've replaced the handle and the blade?

Comment: It is this item: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enola_Gay#Complete_restoration_and_display

Comment: Aztec sacrificial knives are most likely candidates, cause by various accounts they did kill between 10 and 80 thousand people yearly. This surpasses even guillotines in the era of Reign of Terror during French Revolution, tho question remains how much people you could kill with obsidian knife (tecpatl)  before it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Auschwitz-Birkenau, either the whole camp or the gas chambers (depending on your definition of an "item").

Over the period 1941 - 1945 at least 1.1 million people were murdered at the concentration and extermination camp operated by Nazi Germany in occupied Poland.  This includes ~865,000 Jews who were gassed upon arrival and hundreds of thousands of people who died of starvation, exhaustion, disease, individual executions or beatings at the camp.